# Ternary Operations for 2 variables

Tags: ternary-operator

I'd like to ask what is the general opinion about using 2 Ternary operators instead of an if/else block for 2 variables.

Giving an example to make it clearer,

The if/else block:

```
var foo;
var bar;
if (boolean_expression) {
    foo = value1;
    bar = value2;
} else {
    foo = value3;
    bar = value4;
}
```

Using 2 Ternary Operations:

```
var foo = (boolean_expression) ? value1 : value3;
var bar= (boolean_expression) ? value2 : value4;
```

Obviously the if/else block is more efficient, since it only evaluates the boolean_expression once, whereas the 2 ternary operations evaluate it twice.

However, using ternary operations is, in my opinion, so much cleaner and readable, that I've recently decided on sacrificing the minimal efficiency difference between the two of them to improve my code's readability. (Provided the code isn't critical or executed too frequently)

Also, I would weakly argue the same for 3 variables.

Am I doing a horrible thing to my code, or is there a better way I'm not aware?

I'm coding in c#, but I guess this question matters for any language that has the ternary operation.

Comment: You are asking for some opinion based answers here but IMO what you have in the first option is way more readable and brings across the intention of the code a lot better

Answer (score 0):

> I guess this question matters for any language that has the ternary
>   operation

Some languages provide this:

```
(foo, bar) = (boolean_expression) ? (value1, value2) : (value3, value4);
```

Comment: Which language is that? Some interest syntax